# PHP: Extract specific contents to separate variables from block of text in a string

Tags: php

I have a variable called $driveusage that contains the following block of text:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs         rootfs    111G  8.7G   96G   9% /
/dev/sda1      ext3      111G  8.7G   96G   9% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs   59M     0   59M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      61M     0   61M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs      61M  264K   60M   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs      61M     0   61M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs      61M   16K   61M   1% /tmp
```

I need to extract data from the rootfs line only, into separate variables *(i.e. `$drivesize`, `$driveused`, `$drivefree`, not an array)*, just the `size`, `used` and `avail` numbers, and just the numbers only (*including the decimal*).
Keep in mind that the `used` value, once it goes over `9.9G`, will appear as `10G` (*with no decimal point*) and same when avail drops below `10G` will appear as `9.9G`.

I've tried every combination of `preg_replace()` but I'm just not good with those complex expressions. :(

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Where are you getting this text from? You might as well pass it through `awk` or something if it's coming from `exec`.

Comment: It's from a PHP exec_shell call: <?php $driveusage = shell_exec('df -h -T'); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got:

```
$df_info = explode(' ', shell_exec("df -H / | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2,3,4"));
$df = array(
    'size'      => $df_info[0],
    'used'      => $df_info[1],
    'available' => $df_info[2],
);
```

`df -H /` gets human-readable info about your disk, `tail -1` gets the last line of that (the important figures, and `tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2,3,4` gets the second, third, and fourth entries ("size", "used", and "avail") in that row.

Comment: +1 for the unix philosophy, but you should probably explain what you just did there.

Comment: code looks almost perfect, but $df_info[0] returns 119G  I know I can trim the G off with another PHP command on the string, but is there a way to capture it without the G? :)

Comment: Got er workin without the G :) WOOT! `df -H / | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2,3,4 | tr -d 'G'`